# No Xcode CLT listed by Homebrew in macOS High Sierra

Tags: xcode, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

Since updating to macOS High Sierra, Homebrew reports `CLT: N/A`:

```
macOS: 10.13.1-x86_64
Xcode: 9.1
CLT: N/A
```

Previously this entry had reported the version information for the Xcode command line tools.

Do I need to do something to fix this? Is this an expected change with macOS 10.13?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update to High Sierra will remove any command line tools you've installed in the past, making necessary to simply (re)run

```
xcode-select --install
```

to (re)install them.